# VBA - Getting a runtime error '1004' when running this code

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and I am trying to merge two different columns into one column in another worksheet.

My problem is that I get a "runtime error '1004' application- or object-defined error".

From what I have read the error most likely has something to do with `Sheets("Tabelle1")`but I do not know how to fix it.

Here is the code:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim name1 As Range, size As Integer
    size = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(3))

    With Sheets("Tabelle1")
        For Each name1 In Sheets("advprsrv").Range("D2:D" & size)
            If Not (Trim(name1.Value & vbNullString) = vbNullString) Then
                .Cells(name1.Row, 1).Value = LCase(name1.Value & " " & Range(Cells(name1.Row, name1.Column)))
            End If
        Next name1
    End With
End Sub
```

EDIT: I went through the Code with `F8` and it seems that the error pops up at this line `ws.Cells(name1.Row, 1).Value = LCase(name1.Value & " " & Range(Cells(name1.Row, name1.Column).Value))`

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` at the very top of your module and it will help you tremendously with problems like this.

Comment: I think you need a .value at the end of name1.Value & " " & Range(Cells(name1.Row, name1.Column))) as you are concatenating a Range and not the value in the range

Comment: I did not saw that one `.Value` was missing, just tried it out, but unfortunately it did not fix the main problem

Comment: Possibly `Range(Cells(name1.Row, name1.Column))` should have a dot for both `Range` and `Cells`, like: `.Range(.Cells(name1.Row, name1.Column))`, or it should be otherwise qualified to what specific worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below, explanations inside the code comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test2()

    Dim name1 As Range, size As Long
    Dim TblSht As Worksheet
    Dim advpSht As Worksheet

    ' set the worksheet object and trap errors in case it doesn't exist
    On Error Resume Next
    Set TblSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If TblSht Is Nothing Then ' in case someone renamed the "Expense" Sheet
        MsgBox "Tabelle1 sheet has been renamed", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' set the worksheet object and trap errors in case it doesn't exist
    On Error Resume Next
    Set advpSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("advprsrv")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If advpSht Is Nothing Then ' in case someone renamed the "Expense" Sheet
        MsgBox "advprsrv sheet has been renamed", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With advpSht
        ' safer way to get the last row from column "D" (since later on you use it in a Range in Column "D")
        size = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

        For Each name1 In .Range("D2:D" & size)
            If Trim(name1.Value2) <> "" Then
                ' ***** Not sure about the connection between the 2 sheets *****
                TblSht.Cells(name1.Row, 1).Value = LCase(name1.Value2 & " " & TblSht.Cells(name1.Row, name1.Column))
            End If
        Next name1            
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this one. It writes the values from name1 into the new sheet, but it does not connect the other cell with it.

Comment: You had an "error", because you did not know the connection between the columns. I fixed it and now it works perfect. Thanks for this one.

Comment: @fscopulovic I didn't know the connection, and you're welcome :)