# VBA: How to compare two columns in two different worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have only managed to do it when both columns are in the same worksheet.

What I want to do: 
Compare two columns in two different worksheets (worksheet A & B). Cells that only exist in worksheet A but not in worksheet B should be pasted in worksheet B. Same goes for cells that only exist in worksheet B but not in worksheet A. I would also like to have the first row empty for categories. So it should begin counting with the second row.

Can anyone help?

```
Sub test()

Dim d1 As Object, d2 As Object, d3 As Object, e

Set d1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set d2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set d3 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

For Each e In Cells(1).Resize(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Row).Value
    d1(e) = True
    d2(e) = True
Next e

For Each e In Cells(2).Resize(Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(3).Row).Value
    If (d2(e)) * (d1.exists(e)) Then d1.Remove e
    If Not d2(e) Then d3(e) = True
Next e

On Error Resume Next
Range("J1").Resize(d1.Count) = Application.Transpose(d1.keys)
Range("K1").Resize(d3.Count) = Application.Transpose(d3.keys)
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to refer the cells, rows, and etc to a given worksheet. It is not a difficult task, if you do it correctly.

Take a look how to refer to the worksheets:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim shA     As Worksheet
    Dim shB     As Worksheet
    Dim e       As Range

    Set shA = Worksheets(1)
    Set shB = Worksheets("Tabelle2")

    With shA    
        For Each e In .Cells(1).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Row)
            Debug.Print e.Address
        Next e    
    End With    
End Sub
```

As you see the methods are mainly 2:

- By index - `Set shA = Worksheets(1)`
- By name  - `Set shB = Worksheets("Tabelle2")`

There is a third method, by vba's object name, but you probably not need it now. In the example above, pay attention that you are refering three times to the parent `shA` in this line:

```
For Each e In .Cells(1).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Row)
```

- `.Cells(1)...`
- `.(Cells(...`
- `.Rows.Count,..`

This is rather important, when working with worksheets and probably the number 1 mistake in StackOverflow, that people do when working with VBA. E.g. here - [VBA Runtime error 1004 when trying to access range of sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32129567/vba-runtime-error-1004-when-trying-to-access-range-of-sheet) or [VBA - Getting a runtime error '1004' when running this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45568357/vba-getting-a-runtime-error-1004-when-running-this-code?rq=1)

---

If you miss the three time-referring, the `Cells` and the `Rows` from the above range would be automatically referred to the `ActiveSheet`. Which is probably not always the desired case.

Comment: Works perfectly now. Thank you! :)