# Method Range of object worksheet failed when copying dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

I have loop that goes over a range of cells and if a condition is met, I copy relevant data to one sheet and if it doesn't met to another.
I am having a problem when using dynamically the range in order to copy.

I tried to reference the range in 2 different ways but get the same error

```
For i = 2 To lastRow
     Set found= WC.Range("O1:O" & LastInList).Find(SL.Range("G" & i))

    If Not (found Is Nothing) 
        SL.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 3)).Copy Destination:=WC.Range("A" & WCEmptyRow) 'ERROR here
    Else
        'do something
    End If
Next i
```

Also tried:

```
SL.Range("A" & i, "C" & i).Copy Destination:=WC.Range("A" & WCEmptyRow) ' ERROR here
```

How should I reference the cells in row I in order to copy them?

Comment: You test `foundAH` for nothing but you `Set found`. I highly recommend always to activate `Option Explicit` to avoid such typos: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*. • Also specify a worksheet for `Cells(i, 1)` otherwise it might be not in the same sheet as `SL.Range`. • If you get errors **always** tell in which line otherwise we have to guess that. • Also make sure that `WCEmptyRow` and `LastInList` are `>0`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thanks, I have option explicit, the above is a typo (I fixed it). I added the the sheet as you suggested. I am still getting the error.

Comment: You need to fix it here `SL.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 3)).Copy` so it becomes `SL.Range(SL.Cells(i, 1), SL.Cells(i, 3)).Copy`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I added the sheet name before the cells, as you suggested, but still get the same error

Comment: Please check and tell the value of `WCEmptyRow` and `LastInList` then. E.g. output it into immediate window with `Debug.Print WCEmptyRow, LastInList`. I bet `WCEmptyRow` is either not `>0` or the last row `1048576`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thanks! The problem was indeed WCEmptyRow (it was not negative, it was too big, I counted wrong and then added 1 to the last possible line). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

What is `foundAH`? It is not in the code. Make sure tahat the check is for `If Not (foundAH Is Nothing)`. In order to avoid undeclared variables, follow the `Option Explicit` of @PEH from the comments - *In the VBA editor go to Tools › Options › Require Variable Declaration*

Furthermore, the code falls in [number 1 error in the VBA tag in SO - not explicitly declaring parent worksheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47714981/vba-how-to-compare-two-columns-in-two-different-worksheets). See the dots in the amended code:

```
For i = 2 To lastRow
    Set found= WC.Range("O1:O" & LastInList).Find(SL.Range("G" & i))

    If Not (found Is Nothing) 
        With SL
            .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 3)).Copy Destination:=WC.Range("A" & WCEmptyRow)
        End With
    Else
        'do something
    End If
Next i
```